# VBA Excel: Extending & Shortening Cell Range

Tags: vba, excel

Depending on which option button is selected, a different array is loaded into a range of cells (see example below). I want to add the ability to extend and shorten that range of cells (and in turn the array) through a spin button. How would I go about doing that?

Basically what I'm asking: is there a way to add another element to this array and have that be reflected in the range of cells being used?

Add on: there is a graph which represents this range of cells, how would I make that graph's series dynamic? (increase/decrease with the range)

```
Private Sub OptionButton4_Click()

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With


Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim counter As Long
OptionButton4.Height = 26.25
OptionButton4.Width = 87
OptionButton4.Left = 330.75
OptionButton4.Top = 408

Set rng = Range("B2", "AF2")
counter = 0

pwmArray(0) = "0"
pwmArray(1) = "10"
pwmArray(2) = "0"
pwmArray(3) = "10"
pwmArray(4) = "10"
pwmArray(5) = "0"
pwmArray(6) = "10"
pwmArray(7) = "10"
pwmArray(8) = "10"
pwmArray(9) = "0"
pwmArray(10) = "10"
pwmArray(11) = "10"
pwmArray(12) = "10"
pwmArray(13) = "10"
pwmArray(14) = "0"
pwmArray(15) = "10"
pwmArray(16) = "10"
pwmArray(17) = "10"
pwmArray(18) = "10"
pwmArray(19) = "10"
pwmArray(20) = "0"
pwmArray(21) = "10"
pwmArray(22) = "10"
pwmArray(23) = "10"
pwmArray(24) = "10"
pwmArray(25) = "10"
pwmArray(26) = "10"
pwmArray(27) = "0"
pwmArray(28) = "0"
pwmArray(29) = "0"
pwmArray(30) = "0"

If OptionButton4.Value = True Then
    For Each cell In rng
    cell.Value = pwmArray(counter)
    counter = counter + 1
    Next cell
End If
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you've posted, it looks like you're using a static array. You need a dynamic array for this. Chip Pearson has a great [write up on Arrays.](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm) I encourage you to check it out.

So for this scenario, you'd want to do something like this:

```
Option Base 1 '<~~ This sets the lower bound to 1 instead of the default 0

Sub Main()

Dim pwmArray() As Long

ReDim pwmArray(1 To 31)

'Fill your array with values here

'Now if an element needs to be added to the array (and you want to keep _
' the current values) do the following:
ReDim Preserve pwmArray(1 To 32)
pwmArray(32) = x

End Sub
```

Note the `Preserve` keyword. This will keep the values in an array while increasing the size of *only* the last dimension.

Now, the `ReDim` statement is performance hungry, so I generally try to only `ReDim` once if possible in the code (i.e. keeping the `ReDim` outside of loops when possible).

Comment: if you could take a look at my other question, that does a better job of explaining what I'm looking for now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209097/vba-excel-adding-removing-elements-to-array

Answer (score 1):

Untested!

But to dictate the range you could do something like this

```
i = InputBox("Range")
Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(i, 2))
```

This would then set the column to what ever NUMBER they enter so if they put in 3 that would be equal to A2:C2.

As for a spin button I do not know 100% how to integrate that but this at least gives you a start.

Comment: Yeah! I actually had figured that bit out. Now what I'm trying to do is actually add an element to the overall array. Example: `pwmArray(31)=x`.

Answer (score 0):

```
'Imagine the range as a rectangle.
'This crops it by the amounts specified and returns cropped range.
'Use negative numbers to expand the range
Public Function mCropRange(pRange As Range, pFromTop As Long, pFromLeft As Long, _
    pFromBottom As Long, pFromRight As Long) As Range
    Dim lNumRows As Long, lNumCols As Long
    lNumCols = pRange.Columns.Count
    lNumRows = pRange.Rows.Count
    With pRange
        Set mCropRange = Range(.Cells(1 + pFromTop, 1 + pFromLeft), _
            .Cells(lNumRows - pFromBottom, lNumCols - pFromRight))
    End With
End Function
```

## Testing in the Immediate Window

?mCropRange(Range("B2:Y9"), -1, -1, -1, -1).Address

$A$1:$Z$10

?mCropRange(Range("A1:Z20"), 2, 2, 2, 2).Address

$C$3:$X$18